# How to convert string with UTC timediff to mysql datetime

Tags: mysql, datetime, converters

I am having application that fetches data from RSS Feed. Feed item contains pubDate which is of format `Mon, 26 Feb 2018 03:00:00 -0800` like this. I need to save it in mysql database. I am trying to convert the string to datetime using str_to_date function. I don't know what exactly `-0800` is. Here is my code

```
select str_to_date('Mon, 26 Feb 2018 03:00:00 -0800', '%W, %e %b %Y %H:%i:%s %T') ;
```

Its is giving me null, as the last value is not converted. What exactly i have to update with `%T`

Comment: seems to me like a utc time difference, or something of the like. Why not just ignore that last 4 characters (5 including the space) and carry out the `str_to_date()`

Comment: @wookiekim thank you. That works. I did not know i could ignore the character.

Comment: Glad it worked :)

Comment: But i removed `%T` in `str_to_date` function. I did not ignore last 5 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Just ignore the -0800 and run you get the required result.[output after removing the -0800](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0viqD.png)